# Getting result from transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

How Do I get the User record back, instead of Room record for the transaction below?

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return User.forge(data) // here
    .save(null, { transacting: t })
    .then(function (user){
        return Room.forge({ userId: user.id })
        .save(null, { transacting: t });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the chain after the room completes.

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return User.forge(data) // here
    .save(null, { transacting: t })
    .then(function (user){
        return Room.forge({ userId: user.id })
        .save(null, { transacting: t })
        .then(function (){
            return user;
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Promise#tap`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/tap.html).

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return User.forge(data)
    .save(null, { transacting: t })
    .tap(function (user){ // change here
        return Room.forge({ userId: user.id })
        .save(null, { transacting: t });
    })
})
```

Note that it will not be attached to the `User` model unless you use a relation (probably `hasOne` or `hasMany` in this case):

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return User.forge(data)
    .save(null, { transacting: t })
    .tap(function (user){
        users.related('rooms').create({}, { transacting: t });
    })
})
```